# Fresh install from within Ubuntu without CD-ROM or thumbdrive

Tags: system-installation

Suppose I am using Ubuntu version X now. My USB port and optical disk drive are not working properly and I want to do a fresh install of Ubuntu version Y using the downloaded ISO image. Since I cannot install using CD-ROM or thumbdrive, is there any way to wipe out version X completely with version Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a suggestion. Repartition your drive to create a 2 gig partition (at least) install the ISO to this drive using Unetbootin in the type box change to harddisk and select the new partition. Then update grub and reboot. Select the new partition boot to the live image then install to the old partition. As I say its a suggestion don't know if it will work or what problems you may have along the way. But if it works it works.

Comment: did you try to do that anywhere at all?

Comment: No I said it was a suggestion. I would ask Jasper as he marked the answer correct. He might be able to explain any problems with the method.

Comment: @oxwivi I have not tried this method but I accepted the answer to thank Allan for answering, other users be cautioned!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://it.dennyhalim.com/2009/01/boot-iso-image-file-on-usb-hdd-with.html) looks like what you might want. It's the only possible solution I've found.

Another option is to use NetbootInstallFromInternet, instructions can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetbootInstallFromInternet)