# Installing Ubuntu by writing on the Hard Drive

Tags: system-installation

I have a laptop whose CD drive is not operational and is too old to boot from a flash stick. I have bought a new hard drive for it for which I have an enclosure. Is there a way to configure the disk as an external to my current ubuntu setup, copy some form of ubuntu on the hard drive, place the HD in the old laptop, and have ubuntu install ubuntu from there?

Effectively what I am asking about is some sort of live cd that installs on itself (since the HD is writeable).

Comment: You could try this Alexandros http://askubuntu.com/questions/17123/fresh-install-from-within-ubuntu-without-cdrom-or-thumbdrive/17127#17127

Answer (score 1):

Interesting concept - I've never tried it myself but this site [netboot](http://www.netboot.me/) seems to have the option you want

Comment: Clever idea bookmarked mind you they don't have 10.10 ..... yet

Comment: I wonder if I can somehow do that with an Android tablet.